# Find missing data indices using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the optimum way to return indices where 1-d array has missing data. The missing data is represented by zeros. The data may be genuinely zero but not missing. We only want to return indices where data is zero for more than or equal to 3 places at a time. For example for array [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3] the function should only return indices for second segment where there are zeros and not the first instance.

This is actually an interview question :) challenge is to do most effeciently in one line

Comment: My algorithm goes over and finds each place where zeros is, then finds the start and end point, and then sees if it is greater than 2, if it is not then that start end end point is removed. But it is highly inefficient for a very long row of data I have, and I have to store start end end points, I am sure there is a better way of doing it

Comment: a=[1,2,3,4,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0], for this arrayy it is returning [11,12,13] which is not right, it should return all the indices which are not zero, not just 3

Comment: How would `[1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3] ` match anything as there is nowhere that has more than three consecutive zeros?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  Good spot.  I looked at the example and translated his requirement to "three or more", but it's a point that needs clarification as the requirements don't match the example.

Comment: @Chaos:  Your question would be improved by including the working code that you have.  Also clarify whether you want runs of more than three zeros or three or more zeros.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the confusion, if there are 3 or more than 3 consecutive zeros then return the indices, bear in mind that there could be more than one instances where there can be more or equal to 3 zeros consecutively.

Comment: This is actually an interview question :) challenge is to do most effeciently in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep track of the count of zeros in the current run.  Then if a run finishes that has at least three zeros calculate the indexes.

```
def find_dx_of_missing(a):
    runsize = 3 # 3 or more, change to 4 if your need "more than 3"
    zcount = 0
    for i, n in enumerate(a):
        if n == 0:
            zcount += 1
        else:
            if zcount >= runsize:
                for j in range(i - zcount, i):
                    yield j
            zcount = 0
    if zcount >= runsize: # needed if sequence ends with missing
        i += 1
        for j in range(i - zcount, i):
            yield j
```

Examples:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,1,2,3]
>>> list(find_dx_of_missing(a))
[8, 9, 10]

>>> a = [0,0,0,3,0,5,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> list(find_dx_of_missing(a))
[0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

**Edit:** Since you need a one liner here are two candidates assuming `a` is your list and `n` is the smallest run of zeros that count as missing data:

```
[v for vals in (list(vals) for iszeros, vals in itertools.groupby(xrange(len(a)), lambda dx, a=a: a[dx]==0) if iszeros) for v in vals if len(vals) >= n]
```

Or

```
sorted({dx for i in xrange(len(a)-n+1) for dx in xrange(i, i+n) if set(a[i:i+n]) == {0}})
```

Comment: Hi steven your answer is correct, but I am sure there must be a way of doing this more effeciently, maybe in one line

Comment: @Chaos: I'm not sure that making it a one liner makes it more efficient, but here's a one liner: `sorted({dx for i in xrange(len(a)-3) for dx in xrange(i, i+3) if a[i:i+3] == [0,0,0]})`. I create an intermediate set and sort it in order to get rid over overlapping runs of three zeros. (Also, may I go to your job interview?)

Comment: hi Steven, it definitely is a good solution, but is not quite right, 
for a = [0,0,0,3,0,5,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0], it gives [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14], missing 15 at the end :). Furthermore it three zeros are hardcoded, what if we want to make it for n consecutive zeros?

Comment: Change to `sorted({dx for i in xrange(len(a)-2) for dx in xrange(i, i+3) if a[i:i+3] == [0,0,0]})`

Comment: This may or may not be more efficient: `[v for vals in (list(vals) for iszeros, vals in itertools.groupby(xrange(len(a)), lambda dx, a=a: a[dx]==0) if iszeros) for v in vals if len(vals) >= 3]`

Comment: This one is brilliant as we can change 3 to n :) you are a star

Comment: For the `groupby` version change `>= 3` to `>= n`.  For the other change it to `sorted({dx for i in xrange(len(a)-n+1) for dx in xrange(i, i+n) if set(a[i:i+n]) == {0}})`.